# how to delete a node

Tags: c, algorithm

I am trying to delete a node from the list. I must use the function that I used for delete the first node from list and then I must add the other nodes (before the node that I wanted to delete). Functions deletes the node in the beginning of the list and adds to start of the list.

I tried this code:

```
List* Delete_theNode(int the_node){

    List *temp;

    if(head->next == NULL)
    {
        printf("empty list..");
    }

    else
    { 
        for(temp = head; temp!= NULL; temp = temp-> next)
        {
            Delete_node();
        }
        if(temp->number == the_node)
        {
            Delete_Node();
        }

        else
        {
            printf("\n%d there is no such a node\n", the_node);
        }   

    }
}
```

Comment: If you're deleting an arbitrary node from a stack, then you don't have a stack.

Comment: since you received answers dealing with your code, I've rolled back your deleting of the code.

Comment: any reason you changed the title to Norwegian?

Comment: there is no correct answer. I asked the algorithm for delete a node that I searched about using my delete and add functions. These are not the answers, and I stil couldn't fix it.

Comment: leave a comment to each answer kindly explaining why it doesn't answer your question.

Comment: The function does not return a value.

Answer (score 1):

You have many bugs in your code!

This structure is more like a **linked list** and not a **stack**.

You need to know the previous node in order to delete the node and link the list again with the next one.

Additionally you probably have to free the memory on the deleted node before removing it.

Ideally:

```
Stack* Delete_theNode(int the_node) {
    //check if it is on the head
    if (the_node==head->number) {
        Stack * temp = head;
        head = head->next;
        free(temp);
        return;

     }

    Stack* cur = head->next;
    Stack* prev = head;
    //while cur is not NULL and prev is not NULL, this is also legit  
    while (!cur && !prev) { 
        if (the_node == cur->number) {
            Stack *tmp = cur;//the deleted node
            prev->next = cur->next;
            free(tmp);
            return;
        }
        prev = cur;
        cur = cur->next;
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use recursion to add again deleted nodes. I tried to fix but didn't compile so there could be some syntax error. Please verify

```
Stack* Delete_theNode(int the_node){
    if(head == NULL)
    {
        printf("empty stack..");
    }

    else
    { 

        if((head != NULL) && (head->number != the_node))
        { 
            Stack *deletedNode = Delete_Node();//Delete top node & reset the head
            Delete_theNode(the_node); //Recursive Call
            Add_toStack(deletedNode);  //Add node and reset the head
        }

        else if(head->number == the_node)
        {
            Delete_Node();
        }

        else
        {
            printf("\n%d there is no such a node\n", the_node);
        }   

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this using **struct** . Hope it will help you.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

struct node
{
    int number;
    node *next;
};

node a, b, c, d, e, *head, *current, *old, myNewNode;//global
bool flag, token;//global
int deletionInt, searchInt, newInt;//global


 void Deletion ()
    {
        cout << "Enter the integer to be deleted: " ;

    cin >> deletionInt;
old = head;

current = head;

while(1)
{
    if(head==NULL)
    {
        cout << "Your list is empty, nothing to delete here!" << endl;

        break;
    }

    if(deletionInt==current->number)
    {
        if(current == head)
        {
            head= current->next;

            current = head;
        }
        else
        {
            old->next= current->next;

            current = old;
        }
        break;
    }
    if(current->next==NULL) break;

    else
    {
        old = current;

        current = current->next;
    }
}
}
```